# How use if else in mutate function in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `DT_new` with 4 columns :

1. Graduated  (Date format)
2. Work   (Date format)
3. Married  (Date format)
4. Jumlah (Double format)

Sample:

```
 Graduated         Work      Married   Jumlah
2015-05-01   2015-05-02   2015-05-03       20
        NA   2015-05-02   2015-05-03       20
        NA           NA   2015-05-03       20
        NA   2015-05-02           NA       20
```

I need to aggregate `Jumlah` by date in `Graduated` or `Work` or `Married`

- when `Graduated` value is not `NA`, use date from `Graduated`
- when `Graduated` value is `NA` , use another value from `Work` or
  `Married`

format what I want is :

```
     Dates   Total 
2015-05-01      10
2015-05-02      40
2015-05-03      30
```

I have tried `aggregate` with group by in R but just group by 1 column (Graduated), such as:

```
DT_Totals = DT_Total %>%
  group_by(Graduated) %>%
  summarise(Total= sum(Jumlah)) %>%
  arrange(Graduated)
```

How can I handle my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need first create new column and then group over them.

I got function to return first not NA element in vectors defined as:

```
first_not_na <- function(...) {
    Reduce(list(...), f=function(x,y) {
        x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)]
        x
    })
}
```

And you can use it as follow

```
DT_new %>%
    group_by(Date = first_not_na(Graduated, Work, Married)) %>%
    summarise(Total = sum(Jumlah)) %>%
    arrange(Date)
```

or splitting to two steps:

```
DT_new %>%
    mutate(Date = first_not_na(Graduated, Work, Married)) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(Total = sum(Jumlah)) %>%
    arrange(Date)
```

Comment: hi @Marek thx for your answer..i want to ask, function first_not_na is remove NA in what column ? thx

Comment: @ihsansat Look how I use it. It takes two or more columns and try to replace NA in first one using values from others in order which they are given.

Comment: hi @Marek, i have tried you solutions,,,i tried to put into another data.table `DT_newer` , when i View(`DT_newer`) , still row with row with column Dates with values NA :(

Comment: @ihsansat But other dates are NA or not?

Comment: my mistak @Marek, i need to filter my data before use function..it's work...thx :)

Comment: Hi @Marek, if i want to add another columns so column use is  Graduated, Work, Married, Died ,, i has tried to modified your function, i just add '.' in arguments,,..but it's not work "unused arguments" how can fix it? thx

Comment: @ihsansat You don't need to modify it. Just use `first_not_na(Graduated, Work, Married, Died)`. Three dots `...` it's special R symbol used in function to pass undefine number of parameters to function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84639/discussion-between-ihsansat-and-marek).

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new date column using `ifelse`:

```
DT_new %>% 
  mutate(Date1 = ifelse(!is.na(Graduated), Graduated, ifelse(!is.na(Work), Work, Married))) %>% 
  group_by(Date1) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Jumlah)) %>%
  arrange(Date1)
```

#### Update

In case the dates are numeric (Date) type:

```
DT_new %>% 
  mutate(Date1 = ifelse(!is.na(Graduated), Graduated, ifelse(!is.na(Work), Work, Married))) %>% 
  mutate(Date1 = as.Date(Date1, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>% 
  group_by(Date1) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Jumlah)) %>%
  arrange(Date1)
```

Comment: Hi @bergant thx for you answer... i have tried...but it's still make `Date1 ` with value NA :(

Comment: i want ask you, when confirmed = "2015-07-01" Dates1 = "16617"  using mutate function you, want mean about "16617" ? thx

Comment: I guess you have factors in your data. Read the data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or convert your data - for example: `DT_new1$Work <- as.character(DT_new1$Work)`

Comment: @ihsansat `ifelse` is not good in handling dates. 16617 is internal representation of "2015-07-01" date.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ifelse. Factors are consistent only in one column (enumerating different dates). When comparing between different columns you **have to** convert them to character or date type.

Comment: @bergant Yes it does: `ifelse(1==1, Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+1)`

Comment: @Marek Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: @ihsansat See update for converting integers back to dates.